# Format URL format in visualforce page so user can use it in Lightning

Tags: lightning, url

In the visualforce page, we hardcoded the URL link - "Go To List" to show all related account contact role records in a visualforce page. Classic view is working just fine. However, the link is lost when user clicks in Lightning environment. It only displays recent view list view for account contact role object. I am trying to detect user's theme and determine which URL is directing user, but can't get the URL work. Please help! thanks!

```
public PageReference displayAll() {
        try {
            IGT_AccountContactRole__c contactRole = (IGT_AccountContactRole__c) ssc.getRecords().get(0);
            
            Schema.DescribeSObjectResult objDesc = IGT_AccountContactRole__c.SObjectType.getDescribe();
            String prefixId = objDesc.getKeyPrefix();
            
            ApexPages.AddMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Info, prefixId));
            String userTheme = UserInfo.getUiThemeDisplayed();
            String url;
            if(userTheme == 'Theme2' || userTheme =='Theme3'){
              url = '/' + prefixId + '?rlid=00Na000000BA8BX&id=' + contactRole.Account__r.Id;  
            } 
            else
              ???????????????????????? //need help on how to format URL
            PageReference nextPage = new PageReference(url);
            nextPage.setRedirect(true);
            
            return nextPage;
            
        } catch(Exception e) {ApexPages.AddMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Error, e.getMessage()));return null;}
    }
```